# constraint is not valid at this position when running alter table to drop constraints

Tags: mysql, constraints, alter

I created a table using the following command :

```
create table persons(id int not null, 
                     name varchar(100), 
                     age int, 
                     constraint ct_1 unique (name,age),
                     constraint ct_2 unique (id));
```

Then I tried to drop a constraint using the command -

```
alter table persons
drop constraint ct_2;
```

I am getting the following error in Mysql workbench when I hover over this command:

> constraint is not valid at this position for this server version expecting and identifier.

I am not sure what could be the reason for this. It seems to be working on another people computer version information for my MySQL

[image]

Comment: This is not MySQL error message. Look where you put your statement in Workbench. The statements itself are correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4edb2d99f1d8c104b9316b3c96be928c

Comment: How do I checkout what I am using if not MySQL? Although in the version comment it says MySQL community server

Comment: Provide **complete and unchanged** error message text.